# how to convert a list in python to a set according to index number

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list `y=[0,2,1,2,1,1,2,1]` and it has 8 elements (from 0 to 7).

And since it has three unique elements, so three sets will be created.
I want the output to be

```
s1={0}
s2={1,3,6}
s3={2,4,5,7}
```

Comment: automatically creating variables is not the best of ideas. How about `res = {0: {0}, 1: {1, 3, 6}, 2: {2,4,5,7}}`?

Comment: Does the order matter? Do you care about te identity of the elements? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you want to do is to get a set for each unique value in your list that will return indexes of all occurrences of this value in the list.

We can't tell how many sets we will need, therefore we should create a new set for each unique value and hold these sets in a list.

```
y = [0,2,1,2,1,1,2,1]

y_set = set(y)

set_list = []

for unique_value in y_set:
    new_set = set()
    for i, value in enumerate(y):
        if unique_value == value:
            new_set.add(i)
    set_list.append(new_set)
```

This is the result you will get from this approach:

```
[{0}, {2, 4, 5, 7}, {1, 3, 6}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
y = [0,2,1,2,1,1,2,1]
d = {}
for i in set(y):
   d[i] = []
for j in range(len(y)):
   d[y[j]].append(j)
print d
```

Output:

```
{0: [0], 1: [2, 4, 5, 7], 2: [1, 3, 6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` and `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for index, element in enumerate(y):
    my_dict[element].append(index)

result = my_dict.values()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use the value as the key, it's more clear for further steps.

```
y=[0,2,1,2,1,1,2,1]
dict = {}
for i, x in enumerate(y):
    if x not in dict.keys():
        dict[x] = [i]
    else:
        dict[x].append(i)
print dict
```

{0: [0], 1: [2, 4, 5, 7], 2: [1, 3, 6]}

And if you prefer to get the exactly output as mentioned -

```
from collections import OrderedDict
y= [0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]
dict2 = OrderedDict()
dict_seq = OrderedDict()
sequence = 1
list = []
for i, x in enumerate(y):
    if x not in dict2.keys():
        dict2[x] = [i]
        dict_seq['S{0}'.format(sequence)] = dict2[x]
        sequence+=1
    else:
        dict2[x].append(i)
print("dict2 = {0}".format(dict2))
for key, value in dict_seq.items():
    print("{0} = {1}\n".format(key, value))
```

dict2 = OrderedDict([(0, [0]), (2, [1, 3, 6]), (1, [2, 4, 5, 7])])

S1 = [0]

S2 = [1, 3, 6]

S3 = [2, 4, 5, 7]

Comment: can you explain ?

Comment: @aizanzafar for the second solution, I used "sequence" to record the S name which was mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try manual approach:

```
y=[0,2,1,2,1,1,2,1]

groub_by={}

for i,j in enumerate(y):
    if j not in groub_by:
        groub_by[j]=[i]
    else:
        groub_by[j].append(i)
print(groub_by.values())
```

or you can also try itertools grouby approach:

```
list_with_index=[(j,i) for i,j in enumerate(y)]

import itertools
for i,j in itertools.groupby(sorted(list_with_index),key=lambda x:x[0]):
    print(list(map(lambda x:x[1],j)))
```

output:

```
[0]
[2, 4, 5, 7]
[1, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [0,2,1,2,1,1,2,1]
lst_indxs = dict(enumerate(lst))
final_dict = defaultdict(list)
for i,j in lst_indxs.items():
    final_dict[j].append(i)
print(dict(final_dict))
```